# Excel min value greater than x returns 0 if no value found?

Tags: excel, constraints, array-formulas

I am using the following formula:
=MIN(IF(A1:A5>B1,A1:A5))  use Ctrl-Shift-Enter
My value for B1 is 10 and my array is {1,5,4,2,7} so in this case no value is greater than 10.
The problem is that excel returns 0 as the result of the empty set which is a problem as 0 is not greater than 10.
In this case, I can test if the result 0 is greater than 10 and see that the result is invalid, however, if B1 is -10 for an array of {-15,-24,-11,-37-60} than the 0 seems like a valid value when no correct value exists.

So anybody know of how I can find the min or max value of a set with constraints, but return either an error or something distinct if the solution set is empty?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `SMALL` instead of `MIN`, i.e.

`=SMALL(IF(A1:A5>B1,A1:A5),1)`

Unlike `MIN` the `SMALL` function will return an error [#NUM!] for your example

....or if you want a text value instead of an error then use IFERROR function, too, i.e.

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(A1:A5>B1,A1:A5),1),"None")`

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to SMALL and LARGE, but could not get the result. Cannot believe I missed something so simple. Thanks again.

Comment: Also note you have to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter when enter the formula for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your IF statement will return `False` if none of the numbers in the range are greater than 10.  It appears that `MIN` is converting False to numeric (0).  You need to add behavior to handle the False.

If you know that all valid values must be >=0, then you could use the "else" section of the `IF` formula to return -1.

```
MIN(IF(A1:A5>B1,A1:A5,-1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately I cannot assume that all values are positive or even of the same sigh. That data can be completely random.

Comment: I am trying to find some way to make false to some value that will could be ignored if there is a true, but take over if they are all false.

Comment: What about this =MIN(IF(A1:A5>10,A1:A5))/(MIN(COUNT(IF(A1:A5>10,A1:A5)),1))      I divides the value by the min of the count of the same range so if is 0 I get a div/0 error and in other cases it gives the correct value.

Comment: I would like to avoid doing double the work on the same array, but it is the best I have so far? Thanks again.

Comment: also, =IF(COUNT(IF(A1:A5>10,A1:A5))>0,MIN(IF(A1:A5>10,A1:A5)),"none")   this one uses an if to check if there is a valid value first so in those cases it looks at the array only once, and avoids division.

Comment: A simple COUNTIF function would be easier, e.g. `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,">10"),MIN(IF(A1:A5>10,A1:A5)),"none")`.....but you can use `SMALL` in place of `MIN` to return an error, see my answer